# Fixed-size placeholders for figures in twocolumn TeX document?

Tags: floats, minipage, two-column, adjustbox

I am looking for a solution how to implement placeholders of different sizes, framed by colored top and bottom rules, that I can position on different twocolumn pages as desired.

The goal is to replace these placeholders with figures. In the optimal case, the included figure gets "automatically" scaled to fit into the respective placeholder and the caption is below the colored bottom rule.

As shown in my example below, the placeholders should either be positioned at the top/bottom of the page spanning both columns or at the top/bottom of the page with two smaller figures next to each other (each in a single column).

Is such an approach possible with LaTeX? Which packages do I need?
Thx in advance.

[image]

Edit: Here is a MWE, which shows that my approach works well if both figures (i.e. the input PDF files) are equally sized. However, if the original figure sizes differ, the two boxes are no longer identical.

How is it possible to have identical boxes (cf. page 1) for two different figures sizes (cf. page 2)?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{stfloats}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[!b]
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
    {\color{red}\rule{\columnwidth}{0.04cm}}
    \vspace{-0.25cm}
    \scalebox{1.1}{\includegraphics[trim=6cm 18cm 2.5cm 2cm,clip=true,height=7cm]{Test.pdf}}
    {\color{red}\rule{\columnwidth}{0.04cm}}
    \captionof{table}{Test}\label{tab:Test1}
\end{minipage}\qquad
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
    {\color{red}\rule{\columnwidth}{0.04cm}}
    \centering
    \vspace{-0.25cm}
        \scalebox{1.1}{\includegraphics[trim=6cm 18cm 2.5cm 2cm,clip=true,height=7cm]{Test.pdf}}
    {\color{red}\rule{\columnwidth}{0.04cm}}
    \captionof{table}{Test}\label{fig:Test2}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure*}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure*}[!b]
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
    {\color{red}\rule{\columnwidth}{0.04cm}}
    \vspace{-0.25cm}
    \scalebox{1.1}{\includegraphics[trim=6cm 18cm 2.5cm 2cm,clip=true,width=\textwidth]{Test.pdf}}
    {\color{red}\rule{\columnwidth}{0.04cm}}
    \captionof{table}{Test}\label{tab:Test1}
\end{minipage}\qquad
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
    {\color{red}\rule{\columnwidth}{0.04cm}}
    \centering
    \vspace{-0.25cm}
        \scalebox{1.1}{\includegraphics[trim=7.5cm 13cm 2.5cm 2cm,clip=true,width=\textwidth]{Test2.pdf}}
    {\color{red}\rule{\columnwidth}{0.04cm}}
    \captionof{table}{Test}\label{fig:Test2}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure*}

\lipsum[2-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome! If you load the `graphicx` package with the `demo` option, `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}`, the graphics get automatically replaced by the corresponding placeholder. (You can also just add blocks with `\rule{1cm}{2cm}`, say.)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Actually, I am looking for an environment of fixed size (sorry for denoting it as a placeholder), in which I can include my figures. The figures should then be automatically scaled to fit either in the bigger box (see top of the picture) or in one of the two smaller boxes. Does that work e.g. with minipage?

Comment: `adjustbox` has such features but you can specify the width and height already with `\includegraphics`, so I do not understand the question.

Comment: In order to highlight the figures (and tables), I want to frame them with colored rules at the top and bottom. However, in my two-column document, it might be the case that two smaller figures get placed next to each other at the bottom of the page, but differ in their sizes. This means that the "colored borders" are not aligned to each other, which looks weird. I therefore want to have a fixed size for these figures, e.g., 7.35 x 5.85 (cm) and adjust the figure scale accordingly.

Comment: Then please post a code that starts with `\documentclass`, ends with `\end{document}` and can be compiled. This code is supposed to illustrate what you want to achieve, and where you are struggling.

Comment: Thank you, I have posted a MWE to illustrate my problem. Is this understandable or do you need additional information?
In addition to the side-by-side figure illustration, wow should the figure environment look like, if I only have one small figure at the top/bottom and the rest of the page filled with text? Is it then also possible to have the identical size of the "surrounding box"?

Comment: So how does this differ from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/533988/how-to-insert-a-top-and-bottom-rule-for-a-minipage-environment-that-includes-fig ?  Do you want all your figures to be the same height?  Do you want a reserved space on every page for figures only?

Comment: Yes, I want to define various figure environments that are of the same height; e.g.,: 

=> two horizontal figures side-by-side in two columns, height=7cm each
=> two vertical figures side-by-side in two columns, height=10cm each 
=> one horizontal figure in one column, height=7cm 
=> one vertical figure in one column, height=10cm 
=> one horizontal/vertical figure spanning two columns, height=7cm

Within these standardized "spaces", I want to adjust the figure sizes such that they fit into the colored borders. With \scalebox, my top and bottom rules shift (see Table 4 on page 2)